# Uniquness of a QR-Decomposition: Show that there exists an orthogonal diagonal matrix $ S \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $

Tags: solution-verification, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Let $ A=Q_{1} R_{1}=Q_{2} R_{2} $ be two $ Q R $-decompositions of a quadratic matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ with full rank, i.e., $ \operatorname{rank}(A)=n $. This means $ Q_{1}, Q_{2} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ are orthogonal matrices and $ R_{1}, R_{2} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ are upper triangular matrices. Show that there exists an orthogonal diagonal matrix $ S \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ such that it holds
$
\begin{array}{l}
Q_{1}=Q_{2} S^{T} \\
R_{1}=S R_{2}
\end{array}
$.

I do not understand how to find such an orthogonal diagonal matrix. Does anyone have an idea?

I found something very similar online, but unfortunately it does not show how to get to this S:
[How unique is QR?](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Ekkloste/cs515fa14/qr-uniqueness.pdf)

Edit: possible proof

Can someone check if this proof I have written here to the above statement is coherent?

Let $ A=Q_{1} R_{1}=Q_{2} R_{2} $ be two $ Q R $-decompositions of a quadratic matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ with full rank, i.e., $ \operatorname{rank}(A)=n $. This means $ Q_{1}, Q_{2} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ are orthogonal matrices and $ R_{1}, R_{2} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ are upper triangular matrices.

Since A has full rank, A is regular. Because of the regularity of A holds:
$ 0 \ne det(A) = det(Q_1) \cdot det(R_1)= det(Q_2) \cdot det(R_2)$.

Since Q are orthogonal matrices,i.e. $Q^{-1}_1 = Q^t_1 \Leftrightarrow Q_1Q^t_1=I$ and $Q^{-1}_2 = Q^t_2 \Leftrightarrow Q_2Q^t_2=I$, so holds: $det(Q_1) = \pm 1$ and $det(Q_2) = \pm 1$. Thus applies: $det(Q_1)\ne 0$, $det(Q_2) \ne 0$ and $det(R_1)\ne 0$, $det(R_2)\ne 0$. Therefore, $R_1,R_2$ are regular upper triangular matrices.

Then we have
\begin{align} Q_{1} R_{1}=Q_{2} R_{2}, \hspace{3cm} (1)
\end{align}
and left-multiplying by $ Q_{2}^{T} $ and right-multiplying by ${R}_{1}^{-1} $ yields
\begin{align}
{Q}_{2}^{T} {Q}_{1}={R}_{2} {R}_{1}^{-1} \hspace{3cm} (2) 
\end{align}

Note that the right-hand side of Eqn (2) is upper-triangular (since $R_1,R_2$ are).

Let $D:={Q}_{2}^{T} {Q}_{1}={R}_{2} {R}_{1}^{-1}$ be, then $D$ is regular and upper triangular matrix, i.e. $D^{-1}$ is upper triangular matrix and thus $D^t$ is a lower triangular matrix.

But since $D$ is also orthogonal, $D^{-1} = D^t$, where $D^{-1}$ is upper triangular matrix and $D^t$ is lower triangular matrix, which is only possible if $D^t$ and therefore $D$ itself is a diagonal matrix with $D^2=I$.

Thus D is an orthogonal diagonal matrix with entries $\pm1$ on the diagonal.

When left-multiplying Eqn (1) by $ Q_{1}^{T} $ and right-multiplying by ${R}_{2}^{-1} $ gives $D^t= {Q}_{1}^{T} {Q}_{2}={R}_{1}{R}_{2}^{-1} $:

\begin{equation}
\Rightarrow Q_{1} R_{1}=Q_{2} R_{2}\\
\Leftrightarrow Q_1 R_1 R_1^{-1}=Q_{2} R_{2} R_{1}^{-1}\\
\Leftrightarrow Q_1=Q_2D^t
\end{equation}

Multiplying this by its transpose and using orthogonality of $ Q_1, Q_2$ we get $ I=Q_{1}^{t} Q_{1}=\left(Q_{2} D^t\right)^{t}\left(Q_{2} D^t\right)=D Q_{2}^{t} Q_{2} D^t=DD^{T}=D^{2} $. This proves $ D^{2}=I $, so $ D=S $, a diagonal matrix with entries $ \pm 1 $. So $\boldsymbol{Q}_{1}=\boldsymbol{Q_2}\boldsymbol{S^t} $.

Left multiplying Eqn (1) by $ Q_{1}^{t}=S Q_{2}^{t} $ then yields:
\begin{equation}
\Rightarrow Q_{1} R_{1}=Q_{2} R_{2}\\
\Leftrightarrow Q_1^tQ_1R_1=Q_1^tQ_2R_2\\
\Leftrightarrow R_1=SQ_2^tQ_2 R_2\\
\Leftrightarrow R_1=SR_2
\end{equation}
proving that $ \boldsymbol{R}_{1}=\boldsymbol{S} \boldsymbol{R}_{2} $.

If one additionally specifies the condition that $R$ has only positive diagonal elements, this is also true for $R^{-1}$. Since here $D=S={R}_{2} {R}_{1}^{-1}$ is an orthogonal diagonal matrix, it follows with the positivity of the diagonal entries: $D=S=I$. Thus the uniqueness of Q and R follows.

Comment: Contemplate $Q_2^TQ_1=R_2R_1^{-1}$. What orthogonal matrices are upper triangular?

Comment: The right side of the equation should be an upper triangular matrix, because once the product of upper triangular matrices gives again an upper triangular matrix. Here the inverse is also an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: Yes, and the product on the left side is orthogonal. Both properties are true at the same time, thus ...